# Proof of a classical Theorem of Martin-Löf on complexity dips for Kolmogorov complexity,

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, logic, computability, kolmogorov-complexity

I have a question on the first Theorem from the article *Complexity of Oscillations in Infinite Binary Sequences* by P. Martin-Löf, which could be downloaded from [the publisher](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00534110) or [from here](https://github.com/michaelt/martin-lof).

> **Theorem 1:** Let $f$ be a resursive function such that
>   $$
>  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-f(\omega)} = +\infty.
> $$
>   Then, for every binary sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n,\ldots,$
>   $$
>  K(x_1x_2 \ldots x_n | n) < n - f(n)
> $$ for infinitely many $n$.
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

I understand that the function $g(n)$ is constructed to get rid of the constant $c$. But the rest I am extremely unsure:

1) How are the $A_n$ constructed, is here $m = g(n)$ assumed (see the side note in red) because we construct strings of length $n$ by appending strings of length $n - g(n)$ to $x_1 \cdots x_m$? Also latter we use that $x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n \in A_n$ if and only if 
$$
 K_B(x_1 \ldots x_n | n) < n - g(n)
$$
which means there must exist a program $p$ of length $p < n - g(n)$ such that $B(p, n) = x_1\ldots x_n$. But where does this $p$ come from? Has it something to do with the $x_1 \cdots x_m$ used in the construction?

2) Why does $\sum_n \mu(A_n) = \infty$

"force the $A_n$ to circle around the tree [...] therefore, if $x_1x_2 \cdots$
is a fixed infinite sequence, the initial segment $x_1x_2 \cdots x_n$ will belong to $A_n$ for infinitely $n$."

For example if $A_n = (1/2, 1)$ for each $n$ also fulfill $\sum_n \mu(A_n) = \infty$, but here nothing circles around, it just stayes fixed, or if $\mu(A_n) = 1/n$ it will also diverge, but I could easily imagine $A_n$ such that not every infinitely sequence has infinitely many prefixes in infinitely many $A_n$.

Answer (score 1):

No $m$ need not be equal to $g(n)$. In fact $g(n) = m + f(n)$. The construction is concerned with the sequences of lenght $n$ that follow $x_1 \ldots x_m 1\ldots 1$ we are not appending $n - g(n)$ digits (as far as I understand).

For example $m = 2$ $n = 4$ $g(n)=2$  $2^{n-g(n)}-1=3$. The sequences we have are
$$x_1 x_2 1 1\\
x_1x_2 10\\
x_1x_2 01\\
$$
note that it is important to have $g(n) \geq m$ since if $n - g(n)$ is too large, there won't be sequences available.

That is, we might have
 $m = 2$ $n = 5$ $g(n)=3$  $2^{n-g(n)}-1=3$. The sequences we have are
$$x_1 x_2 x_31 1\\
x_1x_2x_3 10\\
x_1x_2x_3 01\\
$$

But we could'n have 
 $m = 4$ $n = 5$ $g(n)=2$  $2^{n-g(n)}-1=7$. The sequences we have are
$$x_1 x_2 x_3 x_41\\
x_1x_2x_3 x_4 0\\
????????????????\\
$$

Comment: For 2. I do not see that the $A_n$ are independent, especially if they share some common prefix. For example $00$ represents the interval $[0, 1/2^{-2})$ and $000$ the interval $[0, 1/2^{-3})$, but both sets are not indepent as their intersection if $[0, 1/2^{-3})$ again?? PS: In your first example is a typo, $2^{n-g(n)} - 1 = 3$, not $=2$.

Comment: Yes Stefan, you are right. I am thinking about it.

Comment: Since each $A_n$ is composed of sequences $x_1\ldots x_m \circ \circ \ldots \circ$ the mere fact that $A_n$ is not empty infinitely often, then $x_1\ldots x_m$ occurs infinitely often.

Comment: Yes, for fixed $x_1\cdots x_m$. I see in the construction that by selecting some fixed $x_1\cdots x_m$ and then always appending combinations, that this occurs in infinitely many $A_n$'s, but I see not that *all* occur that way. For example consider $1,11,111,\ldots$ and the intervals they describe, then for each $n$ the string $1^n$ occurs i.o. but that does not mean that each string $w$ occurs infintely often (and in fact it does not in this example, if some $0$ occurs in $w$ then it occurs just finitely often). Also why $\sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \mu(A_n) = \infty$ (this point may be crucial...)?